# Questions related to recursion

Tags: c, recursion

Please find the code below which shows some operations based on recursion.I would love some one to please explain me how this recursion works?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int func(int);
main()
{
  int ret = 0;
  ret = func(6);
   printf("The val is %d\n",ret);

}

int func(int m)
{
    if((m==0)||(m==1))
    {
       return 1;
    }
    else
    {
      return (func(m-1)+func(m-2));
    }
}
```

When executed,the value of val is 13.Please someone explain how does this unwind operations happens in stack

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to involve a stack or any unwinding (excuse me for involving myself, though).

Just substitute the call with the content of the function, and keep doing that until you no longer recurse:

```
ret = func(6) =
      func(5) + func(4) =
      func(4) + func(3) + func(3) + func(2) =
      func(2) + func(3) + func(1) + func(2) + func(1) + func(2) + func(0) + func(1) =
      func(0) + func(1) + func(1) + func(2) + 1 + func(0) + func(1) + 1 + func(1) + func(0) + 1 + 1 =
      1 + 1 + 1 + func(0) + func(1) + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 =
      3 + 1 + 1 + 8 = 
      3 + 2 + 8 =
      13
```

It's a bit difficult with the typography, but that's what happens and the answer seems to match what you got, too.

Comment: Is the connection between the answer and your name a coincidence :) Nice answer btw.

Comment: @Himanshu No, my nick is chosen to "fit" in programming circles, among other things. :)

Comment: @unwind...Thanks for that simple solution you had provided.I would love to know how this gets allocated in stack and then the deallocation taking place

Answer (score 3):

Recursion is nothing more than calling the a function from within that particular function. A lot of mathematical algorithms or (tree) search algorithms use this technique for their desired result.

Recursive function calls need to 'escape' their repeating 'self calling' otherwise the application would become unresponsive. In your example, this is done by the `if((m==0)||(m==1))` check. If the check is true, the function just returns 1 (and escapes the recursion).

The recursive code you showed calculates the [Fibonacci](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) sequence, which is a typical recursive algorithm, as it requires the values of 2 previous calculations. Step 0 and 1 return `1`. These 2 values are added for step 2 (resulting in `1+1=2`). The next step results in `1+2=3`. And so on. As you see this can only be calculated from the start (and thus requires the recursion to do so)

Answer (score 2):

Your program tries to print the nth(or n+1th) number of a [Fibonacci series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number). Here the base case is when `m =1 or m=0`

The worst thing about recursion here is a value is calculated twice for example func(4), func(3) and func(2) as evident from here.[image]

Comment: did you use any tool to create the diagram?

Comment: ok. I initially thought that there is some tool which automatically generated the trace kind of diagram. Thanks for clarification and efforts to manually create the graphical representation.+1

Comment: Yes :) and for efforts here goes +1 too :)